# Strange Error Seen On Modification Refresh

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am using opencart 2.0.3.1

Since few days, I am facing strange issue.

When I refresh Modification cache ( Admin >> Extensions >> Modifications ), Some pages are Not found error seen. These Not found pages are like register, login, brands etc....

Information pages like about us, contact us etc are working, main home page is also working.....BUT ABOVE SAID FEW are NOT.....

I am not getting...whether it is changing some lines in .htaccess or what ???

I am stucked and unable to add any new extension as New extension installation needs Refresh Modification

Comment: Please check the changes that you've made in the last few days. Also check the third party extensions installed by you.

Comment: What kind of changes you have made ?